# Liferay friendly url with optional param

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, friendly-url

My URL have some params, so i use friendly URLs to solve that ugly URL liferays generates by default.

couple of this params sometimes are empty, that mean its no needed, but other times give me some ID i use for a query.

Example param not `null`:

```
https://myliferay.com/example-portlet/-/example-portlet/search/idTable-7
//it works
```

Example `null` param:

```
https://myliferay.com/example-portlet/-/example-portlet/search/idTable-null
//it works
```

With `null` param it works, but i dont like to see a `null` on my URL.

I want something like `""`:

```
https://myliferay.com/example-portlet/-/example-portlet/search/idTable-
//Doesnt work
```

But it doesnt work, its like the URL doesnt match the friendly URL pattern when a param its empty.

```
   <route>
       <pattern>/search/idTable-{idTable}</pattern>
       <generated-parameter name="idTable">{idTable}</generated-parameter>
       <implicit-parameter name="p_p_lifecycle">0</implicit-parameter>
       <!--more implicit params-->
   </route>
```

How can i specify optionality of a parameter?

Comment: not sure where you get the `null` parameter from: If you generate it yourself, can you generate it as `""`, e.g. empty string? Or transform it to this representation?

Comment: @OlafKock already have an empty string `""` but with the empty param doesnt match the friendly URL pattern. With a `null` it does. I just did the reverse, i change my `""` for `null` to put it working, but as i said, preffer to dont show that `null` in the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its like all vars of friendly url use a regex. You can change/override this regex like this: `{idTable:\d}`

```
<route>
    <pattern>/search/idTable-{idTable:.*}</pattern>
    <generated-parameter name="idTable">{idTable}</generated-parameter>
    <implicit-parameter name="p_p_lifecycle">0</implicit-parameter>
    <!--more implicit params-->
</route>
```

i used `.*` as regex for 0 or more characters, but i dont know if it will bring me problems later. If anyone knows why is not a good idea to use that regex comment it please.

Upgraded the regex with `\d*` to search only digits or empty: `{idTable:\d*}`

Info: [Making URLs friendlier 7.0](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-0/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/making-urls-friendlier)